# Fallback for .NET content place holder?

Tags: asp.net, .net

I am using .net content place holders for a couple areas on my site. The majority of the time they will use one user control for the content. Is there a way in .NET to specify a "fallback" for a content place holder if nothing is passed in from a content page? The place holders are located in my Site.Master FYI

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder>` tag was designed for. Place your default content in the master page, if you don't override the placeholder in a child page the default content is displayed e.g.

**Master Page**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" %>
...
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MyPlaceHolder" runat="server">
    <!-- default content -->
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

**Child Page**

```
<asp:Content ID="ChildPlaceHolder" ContentPlaceHolderID="MyPlaceHolder" Runat="Server">
    <!-- override default content -->
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless I've completely misunderstood what you mean, you can put default content within the `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder>` element in the Master page.  If the corresponding `<asp:Content` element in the client page is not defined, then the default content will be used.

For example, in your Master page...

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="myPlaceHolder" runat="server">
  <b>Hello World</b>
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```